# Insert ZIP File into Database

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, database, winforms

I need to insert an actual *.Zip file into my database. I cannot have it on the server, and my host does not allow to store files outside the publicly-accessilble directory, so that's also out of the question.

Is there anyway to do this? I have made a few searches and have only found forums that have questions, but with no answers that work.

I am using MySQL Connector in C# Windows Forms App. Any help is appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: you are doing it wrong, dude.

Comment: Really? How else would I do this? I'm not allowed to store this file on the server to begin with. But it needs to be stored somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the `BLOB` data type. It's for storing arbitrary binary data.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I *just* found this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-blob.html

Answer (score -1):

Read the zip file as a text file and store it in the database with blob.

You can then retrieve the file by reading the database entry, and write into a new file if you need to serve it for client download.

Comment: varchar for binary data! doh!